# Create curve and use as slider crop image effect

Tags: css, svg

I'm new in css and I have a simple slider, and I want to add curved effect at the end

[image: Desire curve]

So I read about it and I found the easiest solution is to add a curved svg the put inside slider, but how can I add an svg there ?

I tried to create svg curve [here](https://bl.ocks.org/ninestar09/raw/a515ffb3bad328eed8a3/) but it didn't work.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill:#0e4f1f;">
<path d="M -14.73 -1.42 C -1.7 9.78, 8 9.89, 20.9 -1.81">
</svg>
```

My slider image

```css
#main-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
}
```

```html
 <img id="main-slider"  src="https://via.placeholder.com/1365x528?text=Slider">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done by using this value as border-radius

```
border-radius: 0% 0% 60% 60% / 0% 0% 20% 20%;
```

You can play around with the value to achieve different curve radius

```css
#main-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
    border-radius: 0% 0% 60% 60% / 0% 0% 20% 20%;
}
```

```html
 <img id="main-slider"  src="https://via.placeholder.com/1365x528?text=Slider">
```

Comment: I though that values are top,left,bottom, right, but why did you divide it, can you explain that code?

Comment: Every corner can be given two values which define the radius in two directions.  first set of values (horizontal radius) / second set of values (vertical radius)